# How to make a 3x3 matrix that represents weather or not a box on a sudoku board (9x9 matrix) contains x

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am creating a Sudoku bot in python and I need to create a 3x3 matrix where each value represents a box on the board. The value will be *False* if there is an instance of *value* in the box and *True* if not.

Currently I have

```
temp_board = ma.masked_where(board == value, board, True)
boxes = np.full((3, 3), False)
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        boxes[x, y] = not np.any(temp_board.mask[x * 3:(x + 1) * 3, y * 3:(y + 1) * 3])
```

*board* is a 9x9 matrix containing numbers 0-9 but *value* can only equal 1-9

Here is an example of what the output should look like

```
# input
board = np.array([[4, 0, 9, 0, 7, 2, 0, 1, 3],
                  [7, 0, 2, 8, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 6, 0, 4, 9, 8, 7, 0],
                  [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
                  [5, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
                  [6, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 5],
                  [8, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 6, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]])
value = 9
# output

[[False False  True]
 [False  True  True]
 [ True False  True]]
```

The method I am using works but is terribly inefficient, I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, not very subtle, but fast, would be to have a lookup index table

```py
look=np.zeros((9,9,9), dtype=bool)
look[0,:3,:3]=True
look[1,:3,3:6]=True
look[2,:3,6:]=True
look[3,3:6,:3]=True
look[4,3:6,3:6]=True
look[5,3:6,6:]=True
look[6,6:,:3]=True
look[7,6:,3:6]=True
look[8,6:,6:]=True

def inblock(board, blnum, val):
    return val in board[look[blnum]]
```

To get directly you matrix, you can then

```py
~(look*board == value).any(axis=(1,2)).reshape(3,3)
```

`look*board` is a 9x9x9 matrix, filtering only one block each (`(look*board)[k]` contains 0 everywhere, but in block k, which are a copy of the board).

`(look*board == value)` is a boolean version of that.

so `(look*board == value).any(axis=(1,2))` are 9 values, True iff `block[k] contains value`.

Since I use a 1 dimension block array, you can reshape to get 3x3 matrix.

And then negate the result to imitate your output.

Note that there are surely more subtle ways to build the `look` table. For example, using your own for loop, slightly modified. But well, that in only one time.

### Alternative

Just to be even more direct (and, frankly, what I was looking for, when I started to think to your question), would be this

```py
look=np.zeros((3,3,9,9), dtype=bool)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        look[i,j,i*3:(i+1)*3,j*3:(j+1)*3] = True

~np.einsum('ijkl,kl', look, board==value)
```

The fact that I use (3,3,9,9) shape and then avoid reshape is not really the point (it is the same cost, just a presentation problem). I could have done that for the previous solution.

Nor is the fact that this time, I use a double loop to create the `look` table. That again, I could have done it before. It is not `look` that changes. Just the usage of `einsum`. It is not better than my previous solution. But it is what I had in mind at first: use a sort of matrix multiplication.

### Timings

`~(look*board == value).any(axis=(2,3))` : 18.9 μs
(Note this is my previous solution, adapted to (3,3,9,9) shape

`~np.einsum('ijkl,kl', look, board==value)` : 13.6 μs

So, my second solution is not only the one I wanted. But it appears it is also faster.

Comment: I forgot to add timing for your version: 178 μs. Which means that it is not that bad. It not unusual in questions where we replace python for loops by a `einsum` or other pure numpy operations, to have time gain factor in thousands. This `einsum` solution is only 13 times faster than the `for loop` one. Again, may seems a lot (when optimizing code, even a factor 2 is huge). But not that much compared to other cases. Reason is, after all, you only have 9 iterations. Rest of it are numpy operations.